# iOS - Initialising an Array from a file

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to initialise an array from a file

This is the file containing an array of strings .. this is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<string>ccccc</string>
<string>ddddddd</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

I am trying this code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);   
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];   
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"settings-02.xml"];   
NSLog(@"%@",appFile); // debug
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:appFile]; // debug
NSMutableArray *temp = [temp initWithContentsOfFile:appFile];
```

On debugging I see that the app file name is correct and that the file exists.
However the array does not get populated with any objects?

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `temp` before it's assigned.

```
NSMutableArray *temp = [temp initWithContentsOfFile:appFile];
```

Should be like:

```
NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:appFile];
```

Comment: Thanks that works great .. didnt spot the Class Method in the documentation.